# vbscript activating an open window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am creating a macro in VBScript that copies information from an open Internet Explorer application and pastes it in another application. What I DON'T want is to constantly have to reopen a window as the user will already have the desired window open, they want the macro to copy the information from this open window. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim objIE
Dim strMyInfo

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

with objIE
    .visible = true
    .navigate ("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx")
end with
do until objIE.readyState = 4
    wscript.sleep 100
loop

strMyInfo = objIE.document.getElementByID("CodeSnippetContainerCode_b459fc9d-ea49-4d19-8658-1b22d4fff615").value
```

Currently, as I have it, the code above will open a new window each time it's ran. If the user has the window already open, is there a way to put focus on this window rather than opening an new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to an already running Internet Explorer instance like this:

```
For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set objIE = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

The above code will attach to the first Internet Explorer window/tab it encounters. If you have more than one open you need to check them for some distinguishing feature.